# AWS Codepipeline deployment error in for Angular 7 app

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have created pipeline in AWS codepipeline while trying to deploy in elastic beanstalk, I get the following error:

[image: This error is giving in deployment stage]

I am using AWS Codebuild and named artifacts as Sourcearti. In codepipeline input artifact as Sourcearti.

After build stage while deploying to elastic beanstalk above error is giving. Amazon S3 bucket is created and I have created lifecycle also.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. I have edited and configure the Output artifact as Deployment artifact. It is sucessfull